# AWS Glue bookmark error even through bookmarks are disabled

Tags: aws-glue

I have a AWS Glue Python job that loads data from MySQL to S3 files after they are no longer required.

Bookmarks are disabled for the job, however I keep getting the

> IllegalArgumentException: "job bookmark keys List(ip) don't match saved keys Set(id). Use ResetJobBookmark to clear the existing Job Bookmark.

error message.

Did anyone face similar behavior of AWS Glue?

Detailed logs:

> File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/root/appcache/application_1572881176134_0001/container_1572881176134_0001_01_000001/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
>   format(target_id, ".", name), value)
>   py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o91.getDynamicFrame.
>   : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: job bookmark keys List(ip) don't match saved keys Set(id). Use ResetJobBookmark to clear the existing Job Bookmark.

I have reseted the Job Boomkmark for the job, however without any success.

Code that I am using:

```
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job

## @params: [JOB_NAME]
args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['JOB_NAME', 'TABLES'])

#connection init
sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)

#create a list from input argument
tables = args['TABLES'].split(",")

#loop through table list
for table in tables:
    table = table.strip() #remove spaces
    #connect to table
    datasource0 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = "prod", table_name = ("prod_" + table), transformation_ctx = "datasource0")
    #drop fields
    dropnullfields3 = DropNullFields.apply(frame = datasource0, transformation_ctx = "dropnullfields3")
    #only one output file
    dropnullfields3 = dropnullfields3.repartition(1)
    #set path
    s3_path = "s3://aws-glue-output1/" + table
    datasink4 = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(frame = dropnullfields3, connection_type = "s3", connection_options = {"path": s3_path}, format = "parquet", transformation_ctx = "datasink4")

job.commit()
```